# Access Google+ photos from Android app

Tags: android, google-play-services, picasa

Is there an API for accessing photos / albums in Android?

I would like to create photo picker from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Picassa API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide)

This is the Picassa API. Enjoy it.

Comment: @pixel Photos is a sub-app of Google+. Are you sure that photos are not there?

Comment: It's not there. Sorry. That's why I asked this question :)